# MacBook Pro does not go into sleep mode after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade, sleep-wake

I have a MacBook Pro 13″ and after I had upgraded to Yosemite the device does't go in sleep mode when I want it (anything is disconnected from the device). I went to energy power savings to change my settings but still doesn't work.

This is what terminal shows to me with pmset -g assertions command:

2015-01-29 12:02:35 +0100 Assertion status system-wide: BackgroundTask 0 ApplePushServiceTask 0 UserIsActive 1 PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep 0 PreventSystemSleep 0 ExternalMedia 0 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep 0 NetworkClientActive 0

Listed by owning process: pid 76(hidd): [0x0000de4e000908e3] 00:17:53 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" Timeout will fire in 286 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease No kernel assertions.

Comment: Open your Terminal app in the utility folder and type "pmset -g assertions" and report results here, that will tell what is keeping it awake.

Comment: 2015-01-29 12:02:35 +0100 
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 76(hidd): [0x0000de4e000908e3] 00:17:53 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 
 Timeout will fire in 286 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
No kernel assertions.

Comment: this is what terminal shows to me with pmset -g assertions command

Comment: Thanks, now we know you have no settings that will keep it awake. So the next one would be try sleep while running in Safe mode to exclude 3d party stuff.

Answer (score 1):

don't know why but everything went ok and fixed after just two days...thanks a lot anyway! 
Mac